# Using multilevel pointers obtained via cheat engine in own application

Tags: windows, debugging, tools

So I have finished step 8 of the Cheat Engine tutorial and obtained a static address with corresponding offsets to manipulate a value which should be changed to progress in the tutorial. The expression I obtained looks like this

```
[[[[[00645390]+C]+14]+0]+18]
```

I want to go a step further and write a simple (either C++ or C#) program which will access the value stored at this spot and both read from the memory and write to it. What I am not sure about yet is how to access this particularly. I guess it isn't as easy as directly accessing the address `00645390` in memory - do I have to add it to the base address of the application itself? If yes, how may I acquire the address to start working through all those pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need OpenProcess()->ReadprocessMemory() and or QueryVirtualEx()

you can use lkd or livekd to achieve the result

```
livekd.exe
kd> !process 0 0
................
PROCESS 89d1d328  SessionId: 0  Cid: 0238    Peb: 7ffde000  ParentCid: 075c
    DirBase: 14980320  ObjectTable: e14106f0  HandleCount:  23.
    Image: Tutorial-i386.exe
........................
kd> .process /p /r 89d1d328
Implicit process is now 89d1d328
Loading User Symbols
.................
kd> ? poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(645390)+c)+14)+0)+18)
Evaluate expression: 1666 = 00000682]
```

[image: [1]]

here is a sample code that employs `dbgeng functions` from windbg sdk
error checks dbg prints removed for brevity
assumes the module address space is `not randomised / rebased`  (so uses `645390` as it is )
else you may need to find the module base from Ce calculate R`VA from address (645390 -modbase)`
in your code find the modbase and add the calculated rva to read the pointer
`if modbase` in your code was `400000` and `rva` was `1390` use `401390` instead of `645390`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <engextcpp.hpp>
int __cdecl main( void  ){
    IDebugClient*     g_Client      = NULL;
    IDebugControl*    g_Control     = NULL;
    IDebugSymbols*    g_Symbols     = NULL;
    IDebugDataSpaces* g_Data        = NULL;
    ULONG             Pid           = NULL;
    ULONG             bytesread     = NULL;
    ULONG             ptr           = NULL;
    DebugCreate( __uuidof(IDebugClient), (void**)&g_Client );
    g_Client->QueryInterface( __uuidof(IDebugControl), (void**)&g_Control );
    g_Client->QueryInterface( __uuidof(IDebugSymbols), (void**)&g_Symbols );
    g_Client->QueryInterface( __uuidof(IDebugDataSpaces), (void**)&g_Data );
    g_Client->GetRunningProcessSystemIdByExecutableName(
        0,"Tutorial-i386.exe",DEBUG_GET_PROC_ONLY_MATCH,&Pid);
    g_Client->AttachProcess(0,Pid,DEBUG_ATTACH_NONINVASIVE);
    g_Control->WaitForEvent( 0, INFINITE );
    g_Data->ReadVirtualUncached(0x645390,&ptr,sizeof(ptr),&bytesread);
    g_Data->ReadVirtualUncached((ptr+0xc),&ptr,sizeof(ptr),&bytesread);
    g_Data->ReadVirtualUncached((ptr+0x14),&ptr,sizeof(ptr),&bytesread);
    g_Data->ReadVirtualUncached((ptr+0x0),&ptr,sizeof(ptr),&bytesread);
    g_Data->ReadVirtualUncached((ptr+0x18),&ptr,sizeof(ptr),&bytesread);
    printf("%-15s%d\n","5th lvl ptr =", ptr);
    g_Client->DetachProcesses();
    return 0;
}
```

[image]